# The login with Facebook keeps asking to authorize my app

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I've read somewhere that `offline_access` is/will be deprecated.

If I understood correctly this means that every time my user clicks on "Login with Facebook" in my page he/she will be redirected to the Oauth Facebook page and will have to authorize the App again.

Is this correct?  Are the users really used to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, offline_access has nothing to do with login screens and they will only get the auth dialog if you change the list of permission request defined in your `scope` or if they removed/revoked your application from their app listing.

Once they accept the app, then they won't need to see that screen again.  Depending on how you have configured and programmed you app, they might see a flash of the dialog as it loads up and then closes very quickly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.   In my case I've tested with my own app and the example (non-js) that comes with the SDK and both give me the same result, even tough I am logged in with facebook (I mean I can access my page at facebook), when I click on the "Login with Facebook" button in my app I get that authorization popup....

Comment: I've got dozens of apps and none of them do this.  Here's and example:  http://jsfiddle.net/dmcs/R4g47/3/  try clicking [login with facebook] after you've auth'd the app, it won't show the popup again.

Comment: Strange.  Could it be something with the scope?

Comment: All of my apps have different scopes.  Some have all, some none, and many with different ones selected.  The only thing that would cause the dialog to reappear would be if the user removed the app or you changed the scope.

Comment: Thanks.  That was it. Each I tested the scope was changed.